# Is possible do Select * form DynamicValue to perform a query like this in Navision?

Tags: sql, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

Is possible do Select * form DynamicValue to perform a query like this in Navision?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok thanks man, but the question is quite simple hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform a sql query li this `select * from DynamicValue` You must do something like this.

Imagine that you have a table and you are going to show the data in a page or form.

*Variables:*

```
RecDynamicValue (Table).
PagDynamicValues (Page).
```

*Code:*

```
RecDynamicValue.RESET; //Clean filters
CLEAR(PagDynamicValues);
PagDynamicValues.SETTABLEVIEW(RecDynamicValue); //Set RecDynamicValue (Table)
PagDynamicValues.RUN; (Open Page)
```

In this code when page is open you can see al records from **DynamicValue** table like a `Select * from DynamicValue`.

If you need perform a loop for all records from **DynamicValue** table in code try this:

```
RecDynamicValue.RESET;
IF RecDynamicValue.FINDSET THEN REPEAT //Repeat clausule for a loop
  //Loop...
  //Loop...
  //Loop...
UNTIL RecDynamicValue.NEXT = 0; //Repeat until last value
```

In all cases first you need declare a variable, `SubType = Record` and specified ID or name of record.
You can not change the value of the table variable by code.

***But perhaps you can use `RecordRef` function to do that.***

*For example:*

```
RecRef.OPEN(27); //Id of ItemTable    
RecRef.FINDFIRST;
FldRef := RecRef.FIELD(3); // Item.Description;
FldRef.VALUE('New description');
RecRef.MODIFY;
```

In your case your **DynamicValue** is parameter to `RecRef.OPEN("Your Dynamic Value")` here you need specified value ID of your table.

You can also perform a loop using **RecorRef**.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not dynamic because you need to set on variable the subtype of variable. I wanted to change "Subtype" of variable Table by code, so i need found some manner to change this attribute or maybe other manner of take the table.